# Using Pulumi automation API to deploy GCP instances in an http framework does not work

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, pulumi

When I deploy a GCP compute instance from a script eg `test_deploy.py` using the Pulumi Automation API the instance is deployed without a hitch. When I run the exact same code from a Django POST endpoint one of two things happen. If I run the deploy against an existing stack it will delete the running instance. If I run the deploy on a new stack nothing happens. Is there some setting I am missing? What is weird this does not happen when I deploy Firewalls or VPC,s via the endpoint. Everything will work as expected. code:

```
########## instance_stack.py##################
class DeployVmInstance(BaseStack):
    def __init__(self,
                 project_id,
                 subnet_name,
                 stack_name,
                 stack_region,
                 stack_zone,
                 instance_tags,
                 image_name,
                 disk_size=DEFAULT_DISK_SIZE,
                 machine_type=DEFAULT_VM_HOST_MACHINE_TYPE,
                 timeouts=DEFAULT_TIMEOUTS,
                 desired_status=DEFAULT_VM_DESIRED_STATUS):
        self.subnet_name = subnet_name
        self.stack_name = stack_name
        self.project_id = project_id
        self.project_name = f'{self.stack_name}-vm'
        self.vm_name = self.project_name
        self.stack_region = stack_region
        self.stack_zone = stack_zone
        self.machine_type = machine_type
        self.instance_tags = instance_tags
        self.disk_size = disk_size
        self.timeouts = timeouts
        self.image_name = image_name
        self.desired_status = desired_status

    def set_instance_status(self, status):
        self.desired_status = status

    def create_stack(self):
        '''
        Create instance
        '''
        subnet = compute.get_subnetwork(name=self.subnet_name,
                                        region=self.stack_region)    
        vm_instance = compute.Instance(self.vm_name,
                                       desired_status=self.desired_status,
                                       machine_type=self.machine_type,
                                       advanced_machine_features=FEATURE_ARGS(enable_nested_virtualization=True), # noqa
                                       boot_disk=BOOT_DISK_ARGS(
                                           initialize_params=BOOT_INIT_ARGS(
                                               image=self.image_name,
                                               size=self.disk_size
                                            )
                                        ),
                                       network_interfaces=[NETWORK_ARGS(subnetwork=subnet.id)], # noqa
                                       tags=self.instance_tags,
                                       zone=self.stack_zone)

        network_ip = vm_instance.network_interfaces[0]['network_ip']
        pulumi.export('network_ip', network_ip)
        pulumi.export('boot_disk', vm_instance.boot_disk.source)
        pulumi.export('boot_disk_name', vm_instance.boot_disk.device_name)

    def deploy_stack(self):
        '''
        Deploy stack
        '''
        stack = auto.create_or_select_stack(stack_name=self.stack_name,
                                            project_name=self.project_name,
                                            program=self.create_stack)
        stack.set_config("gcp:project", auto.ConfigValue(self.project_id))
        up_res = stack.up(on_output=print)
        return up_res.outputs

############test_deploy.py(works fine)############################
from instance_stack.py import DeployVmInstance

PROJECT_ID = '***************'
DEFAULT_REGION = 'us-central1'
new_vm_tags = ['test-vm']
new_vm = DeployVmInstance(project_id=PROJECT_ID,
                          subnet_name='testvm-dimcorp-subnet',
                          stack_name='test-created-vm',
                          stack_region=DEFAULT_REGION,
                          stack_zone='us-central1-b',
                          instance_tags = new_vm_tags,
                          image_name="****/global/images/ubuntu")
                          new_vm.deploy_stack()

############# From Django launch view.py(does not work)############
# Bad behavior includes deleting existing stack when run
# or Running new stack with no instance being deployed.
# no errors displayed.

from instance_stack.py import DeployVmInstance

PROJECT_ID = '***************'
DEFAULT_REGION = 'us-central1'


class ImageLaunchView(APIView):
    def post(self, request, pk, format=None):
        new_vm_tags = ['test-vm']
        new_vm = DeployVmInstance(project_id=PROJECT_ID,
                          subnet_name='testvm-dimcorp-subnet',
                          stack_name='test-created-vm',
                          stack_region=DEFAULT_REGION,
                          stack_zone='us-central1-b',
                          instance_tags = new_vm_tags,
                          image_name="****/global/images/ubuntu")
       new_vm.deploy_stack()
```

Comment: Can you share some code? It’s going to be difficult to tell what’s going on otherwise

Comment: Are you getting any errors/warnings? You must use Pulumi or you could try other like terraform?

Comment: @PiersKarsenbarg Added code for context.

Comment: @PjoterS We found pulumi to be a better fit for our project than Terraform...except for this instance(pun intended) where it has been a real drag.